# Why is preg replace not accepting array

Tags: php

I am trying to add foreach statements with `preg_replace` but it keeps throwing the error `preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array` Because of the `foreach` that deals with the `vars` it wont allow me to place arrays. How can I make it use both?

here are the `class`

```
private $vars = array();

public function assign($key, $value) {
    $this->vars[$key] = $value;
}

public function render($file_name) {
    $path = $file_name . '.html';

    if (file_exists($path)) {

        $content = file_get_contents($path);

        foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value) {
            $content = preg_replace('/\{' . $key . '\}/', $value, $content);
        }

        /* PHP Tags */
        $content = preg_replace('/\{php\}/', '<?php ', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/\{\/php\}/', ' ?>', $content);

        /* IF Statement */
        $content = preg_replace('/\{if (.*)\}/U', '<?php if ($1): ?>', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/\{elseif (.*)\}/U', '<?php elseif ($1): ?>', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/\{else\}/U', '<?php else: ?>', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/\{\/if\}/U', '<?php endif; ?>', $content);

        /* FOREACH Statement */
        $content = preg_replace('/\{foreach (.*)\}/e', '<?php foreach ($1) { ?>', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/\{\/foreach\}/e', '<?php }; ?>', $content);

        eval(' ?>' . $content . '<?php ');
```

here is the variable file

```
include_once 'gate.php';

$gate = new Gate;

$gate->assign('pagetitle', 'Test Document');
$gate->assign('username', 'Zach');
$gate->assign('age', 21);

$names = array(
        "Name",
        "Name2",
        "Name3",
        "Name4"
    );

$gate->assign('members', $names);

$gate->render('test');
```

and here is the HTML

```
{foreach ({members} as $member)}
       <p>$member</p>
{/foreach}
```

I just need to know how to fix the error which i assume involves making the array become accepted by the `preg_replace` function

Comment: I don't really have an idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I am trying to get the error to go away

Comment: More simply put i just need the `preg_replace` to accept the array. Does anyone know

Comment: This is not your real code ([proof](http://ideone.com/TvXmXm)).

Comment: @zachstarnes: I don't think we are in the same conversation.

Comment: @zachstarnes: I put it there. It's a copy/paste of what you posted above. **It does not produce the error you mention. Conclusion: you have not shown us the code that produces the error.**

Comment: @Jon there is the whole class. What you see is what i have

Comment: `foreach ($this->vars as $key => $value) { $content = preg_replace('/\{' . $key . '\}/', $value, $content); }` You assign values elsewhere in the code. What happens if `$value` is an array? I think that would be your problem.

Comment: @Waleed Khan okay that helps me a little but how can i make it work then?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `$gate->assign('members', $names)`, where `$names` is an array? When the content contains `{members}`, what should it replace it with?

Comment: @Barmar I want it to act like a normal `foreach` statement so the `{members}` would be the whole array you are looping through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `$names` to a string containing the PHP code to create a literal array:

```
$names = 'array(
        "Name",
        "Name2",
        "Name3",
        "Name4"
    )';

$gate->assign('members', $names);
```

Comment: If these names are ever meant to be dynamic, be *very careful* to have them escaped. Or build in some sort of array-unpacking functionality.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help the error is no longer there. Will this loop through just like a normal array?

Comment: It will if the output of your template code is evaluated by the PHP processor again. That seems to be what you expect with your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Nothing in the code you showed does that. It looks like it's taking a template file and writing a PHP file. I assume some other piece of the system executes that PHP file.

Comment: @barmar if you dont see anything that does then thats a problem because thats all the code I have lol :(

Comment: @Barmar if this would be easier In a chat lets start one

Comment: Now I see it -- there's an `eval()` at the end of `render()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29762/discussion-between-zachstarnes-and-barmar)